# Mapping only specific foreign items from huge tables in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, list, foreign-keys

If I have an object type that have multiple instances (in this case thousands) of another object type.

```
public class A
{
    public virtual IList<B> Bs { get; set; }
}
```

But I only need two of them mapped to the object, so whenever I access Bs the list is the first and the last without needing to load all them?

Seems a waste to hold thousands of objects in memory in EntityFramework if they're not even used. Especially in a Real-Time environment (the rest of the objects are used in another context and are still needed).

Is this possible?

```
public class A
{
    public virtual B First {get; set;}
    public virtual B Last { get; set; }
}
```

With it still being a full list of plenty of these objects in database, but EntityFramework only loads first and last of them.

Comment: maybe you can set `Bs` to be lazy loaded and run `.Last` and `.First` on it (from linq)? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd456846(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: NHibernate has formula properties. EF doesn't. But it should be something like that. With EF the only alternative is to use a non-entity class, call it a domain class, a DTO, a view model, whatever. With available mapping methods you can't achieve this.

Comment: Do you know what two you need?

Comment: Always first and last item in list.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work for you...

```
using (var context = new Cde_Entities())
{
    var instanceA = context.A.SingleOrDefault(x => x.AId == aid);

    var first = context.Entry(instanceA).Collection(x => x.B).Query().OrderBy(x => x.BId).FirstOrDefault();
    var last = context.Entry(instanceA).Collection(x => x.B).Query().OrderByDescending(x => x.BId).FirstOrDefault();

    instanceA.First = first;
    instanceA.Last = last;

    return instanceA;
}
```